# Read multiple hex values from single line

Tags: fortran, hex, fortran90, readfile

I want to read a set of hex values which are arranged in a line, but number of spaces between each value is not determined. How I can read this in Fortran 90. For instance:

> 2F4----33--6B5----------4DB3

```
program ReadSomeHex

implicit none


integer:: Decval , Decval2 , Decval3 , Decval4 , i

Open(1,File='Input.txt')

Open(2,File='Output.txt')


read(1,'(Z4,Z4,Z4,Z4)') Decval , Decval2 , Decval3 , Decval4

write(*,*)        Decval , Decval2 , Decval3 , Decval4

end program ReadSomeHex
```

Answer (score 3):

With "unformatted" input (by which I now mean formatted (i.e. text) fortran input which doesn't follow a specific fixed format; not to be confused with actual unformatted input **[NB]**) your best option is probably to read in the hexa values as strings, then perform a fixed-format (rather than list-directed) read on the strings:

```
program ReadSomeHex

implicit none

character*4 :: Hexval, Hexval2, Hexval3, Hexval4
integer:: Decval , Decval2 , Decval3 , Decval4 

Open(1,File='Input.txt')
Open(2,File='Output.txt')

read(1,*) Hexval, Hexval2, Hexval3, Hexval4
read(Hexval,'(Z4)') Decval
read(Hexval2,'(Z4)') Decval2
read(Hexval3,'(Z4)') Decval3
read(Hexval4,'(Z4)') Decval4

write(*,*)        Decval , Decval2 , Decval3 , Decval4

end program ReadSomeHex
```

Note that you should make sure that each of your hexa numbers are at most 4 characters long.

**[NB]** If you don't specify otherwise during `Open`, fortran assumes you mean formatted input/output, i.e. a text file.

Comment: Unformatted means binary in Fortran. Did you mean list-directed?

Comment: @VladimirF I'm admittedly uncertain about the terminology. Please let me know if it's still ambiguous, or feel free to edit my answer if you feel like it.

Comment: I'd probably go for "unstructured".